# CSS assets paths in 3rd party libraries when using jsbundling-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, jsbundling-rails, cssbundling-rails

I'm in the process of updating my Rails app to version 7.  As part of this, I've removed Webpacker and am trying to move my whole assets solution to the new jsbundling-rails and cssbundling-rails gems.   So far it's working really nicely and is a lot simpler.

One of the things that does not appear to be working are images referenced in CSS files that are a part of a 3rd party library such as Photoswipe.

The library itself works but the images fail.  Photoswipe includes a SCSS variable for the path to the skin and when I was using Webpack I had this line set as below:

```
$pswp__assets-path: "../../../node_modules/photoswipe/src/css/default-skin/"; // path to skin assets folder (preloader, PNG and SVG sprite)
```

This is now failing, I've tried soooo many combinations of things but I cannot for the life of me seem to be able to get those images working.

This is not just a Photoswipe issue, it's happening in a number of other libraries where images are being referenced.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you find a way? I'm running into the same issue

Comment: The conversation apparently continued on GitHub, not sure if it resolved though https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails/issues/62